# How to execute a batch script from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, windows, iis, batch-file

Server Specs
Windows 2008Rc2
IIS7
mysql
PHP 5.3

I have a batch file that does a mysql dump and then zips up the contents and makes it available for download in a public folder. Now i know this scripts works because it runs fine every-time i run it manually, but i can't seem to get it to work through php.

Basically I would like to just be able to call a php page that will run this batch file.

I know that exec is enabled as im able to use shell_exec to ping google.com, and i can get the output back.

I've tried with just system() and exec(), but still nothing. In some cases it looks like the page is working, but it just sits on the loading prompt.

I've searched high and low trying a million different combinations of commands, but none of them seem to work for me.

I've been reduce to trying this simple command, as i can get ping to work from this. Although when the page is called it only displays the echo statements.

```
<?php

echo "Starting...";

echo shell_exec("C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DBZIP2");

echo "Success!";

?>
```

I've also tried this, but the page just hangs on a loading screen and doesn't display the echo commands.

```
<?php

    echo "Starting...<br><br>";

    system("cmd /c START C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DBZIP2");

    echo "Success!";

?>
```

Not really sure where to go from here. I've tried pathing the cmd.exe file, but that made no difference. Is there an easier way to do this? Another programming Language perhaps? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need \\ in place \ in your path ? See some comments on [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) page.

Comment: I tired this as well... it made no difference in the outcome

Answer (score 0):

Try executing using "shell_exec" with a full path to CMD.exe

```
<?php
    echo "Starting...<br><br>";
    shell_exec("c:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c START C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DBZIP2");
    echo "Success!";
?>
```

Comment: I had already tried this, when the command is run like this the page sits on the loading screen and the echo statements fail to load.